# how to get id from url from mywebsite.com/company/3/3-CompanyName.html

Tags: php, .htaccess

How do I get the id from the url `mywebsite.com/company/3/3-SofdiaTechnology.html`

Using .htaccess I changed the url from `company.php?id=3&name=CompanyName` to `mywebsite.com/company/3/3-SofdiaTechnology.html`
here 3 is the id to retrieve from database i have to get value of id from url
Please suggest a solution to get the id.

The rewrite rule used is:

```
RewriteRule ^company/(.+)/company-(.+)\.html$ company.php?id=$2&name=$1 [nc]
```

The link is:

```
<a href="company/<?=$row['id'];?>/company-<?=$row['id'];?>-<?=$row['business']; ?>.html" >29</a>
```

Comment: Why is the id in the URL twice?

Answer (score 0):

You can get id by using below code in `company.php`.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

A rewrite basically tells apache to read your nice new URI as a URI that the system can understand. So when somebody accesses `/company/3/3-SofdiaTechnology.html`, the id is `$_GET['id']`.

```
RewriteRule ^company/(.+)/company-(.+).html$ company.php?id=$2&name=$1
```

This rule tells the system to treat the first bit like the second bit, so you still have access to `id` and `name` as get variables.

Answer (score -1):

If your url is same for every company you can get by the following code

```
<?php 
$str="mywebsite.com/company/3/3-SofdiaTechnology.html";
$arr=explode("/", $str);
echo $arr[2];?>
```

Comment: There's no need for any URI parsing, that's way over complicated for what is actually needed. Ignoring that fact, you're treating the URI like it's just a pre-defined string, when it should be `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.